# How do I make the ploy show in my df analysis

Tags: python, plot

I have a dataframe of emails that has three columns: From, Message and Received (which is a date format).

I've written the below script to show how many messages there are per month in a bar plot.

But the plot doesn't show and I can't work out why, it's no doubt very simple. Any help understanding why is much appreciated!

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('XXX')
df = df[df['Message'].notna()]

df['Received'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Received'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

df['Received'].groupby(df['Received'].dt.month).count().plot
```

Comment: also add parenthesis after plot: `...count().plot()`

Answer (score 0):

A `pyplot` object (commonly `plt`) is not shown until you call `plt.show()`. It is designed that way so you can create your plot and then modify it as needed before showing or saving.

Also checkout [plt.savefig()](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html).